# Word automation. CC checkboxes should be inserting a quick part into a cc richtext field

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have several cc checkboxes that need to insert a specific / relevant quickpart into an associated rich text field... but it's not working!!! I'm just trying to get one checkbox ("AQA_Yes") working and then will add the others. One the check box is selected, it should be inserting the quick part "Recall" into the rich text field "CC_All". If the check box is de-selected, then the quickpart should be removed and the rich text field set to a width of 0. The first error occurs on the "Select Case ContentControl.Title" line -- Run-Time Error '424': Object Required.  The next problem is trouble defying the "objBB.Insert Selection.Range" line. I need to modify the line so that it inserts the Recall quickpart into the CC_All rich text field; but I'm not certain of the code here.

```
Sub CheckBox_Click()
    Select Case ContentControl.Title
    Case "AQA_Yes"
        recallObj = "Recall"
        RichText = True
        If ContentControl.Checked Then
            InsertExistingBuildingBlock ("Recall")
        End If
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl)
    Call CheckBox_Click
End Sub

Sub InsertExistingBuildingBlock(BuildingBlockTitle As String)
    Dim objTemplate As Template
    Dim objBB As BuildingBlock
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Set cc = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("CC_All")
    Set ccObj = Selection
    ' Set the template to store the building block
    Set objTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
    ' Access the building block through the type and category
    Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeQuickParts) _
    .Categories("General").BuildingBlocks(BuildingBlockTitle)
    ' Insert the building block into the document replacing any selected text.
    objBB.Insert Selection.Range
End Sub

Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, _
        Cancel As Boolean)
    Call CheckBox_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Please also take a moment to read the guidelines on posting questions on StackOverflow. You need to explain HOW it doesn't work, what the current behavior is and what the expected/desired behavior would be. It's difficult to be sure with the badly formatted code, but it seems to me you'd be getting error messages. If you are, what are they and what line is triggering them?

Comment: Thanks Cindy... on my screen, it seems that the formatting is good (perhaps you corrected it?). I do get an error message currently at the "Select Case" line... it also errors on the [objBB.Insert Selection.Range] line. Oddly, it worked one time and then stopped working -- go figure.

Comment: Thanks Cindy... I edited as suggested.

Comment: Note that you should post only one question in a "Question" - that's StackOverflow policy. I've made an exception, here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, you aren't passing the ContentControl object to the procedure Checkbox_Click, so VBA doesn't know what it is. Try this:

```
'Note: Also for OnExit!
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl)
  Call CheckBox_Click(ContentControl)

Sub CheckBox_Click(ContentControl as Word.ContentControl)
  Select Case ContentControl.Title
```

For the second, you need to get the Range of the "target": a location inside the RichText content control. The problem is, you don't really have a content control object, yet. I believe this is the one you want, but you're missing a couple of things:

```
Dim cc As ContentControl
'Doesn't work as it stands
Set cc = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("CC_All")
```

1. ALWAYS use ActiveDocument, not ThisDocument unless you know you need ThisDocument (you don't)
2. SelectContentControlsByTag does not return a single content control. It returns an array of content controls because more than one content control can have the same title and/or tag. If you're sure you have only the one, or want the first, then you can specify that index as part of the line of code.

So something like the following should work:

```
Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Test")(1)
Dim rngCC as Word.Range
Set rngCC = cc.Range
objBB.Insert rngCC
```